# Using System.IO.Abstractions with DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, moq

How can I write unit tests using Moq for `DirectoryInfo`? My class is as below:

```
public class DataProcessor : IDataProcessor, IDisposable
{
    private ILogger _logger;
        
    DataProcessor(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Run(string filePath)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo( filePath);
        var filesInDir = dir.GetFiles("*.xml");

        foreach(var filePath in filesInDir)
        {
            // process file
        }   
    }
}
```

I tried using System.IO.Abstractions and changed my class as below but `DirectoryInfo` does not work with System.IO.Abstractions

```
public class DataProcessor : IDataProcessor, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;

    private ILogger _logger;
        
    DataProcessor(ILogger logger) : this(new FileSystem())
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    internal DataProcessor(IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        _fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    public async Task Run(string filePath)
    {
        var dir = new _fileSystem.DirectoryInfo(filePath);// ERROR HERE
        var filesInDir = dir.GetFiles("*.xml");

        foreach(var filePath in filesInDir)
        {
            // process file
        }             
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> The name or namespace name '_fileSystem' does not exist.

Is this because I am not doing it right or this can't be done?

Comment: What do you expect `var dir = new _fileSystem.DirectoryInfo( filePath);` to do?  The `new` operator expects a type to follow (`class Xyz {}` and then `var xyz = new Xyz();`).  You are passing it whatever `_fileSystem.DirectoryInfo` returns.

Comment: Use `IFileSystem.EnumerateFiles` instead of `new DirectoryInfo( filePath)`

Comment: If you are going to abstract out the IO functionality then I suggest doing it explicitly

Comment: I want to iterate through the directory with all xml files. How else do I use System.IO.Abstractions so that I can mock it

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)..The tight coupling to implementation concerns and Single Responsibility Principle violations make isolating the code for unit tests difficult. Consider reviewing and redesigning the subject under test.

Comment: @user2837961 if you are using an abstraction for the file access, then use the methods from the abstraction to do what you want. You might want to pay attention to the comments too.

Answer (score 9):

You can instantiate an `IDirectoryInfo` object using:

```
IDirectoryInfo directory = _fileSystem.DirectoryInfo.FromDirectoryName(filePath);
```

So your full code would look like:

```
public class DataProcessor : IDataProcessor, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;
    private ILogger _logger;
    
    DataProcessor(ILogger logger) : this(new FileSystem())
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    internal DataProcessor(IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        _fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    public async Task Run(string filePath)
    {
        var dir = _fileSystem.DirectoryInfo.FromDirectoryName(filePath);
        var filesInDir = dir.GetFiles("*.xml");

        foreach(var filePath in filesInDir)
        {
            // process file
        }           
    }
}
```

As for your unit tests, I recommend following the `System.IO.Abstractions` example shown on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions). You can mock your file system like this:

```
[Test]
public void DataProcessorTestName()
{
    // Arrange
    var fileSystem = new MockFileSystem(new Dictionary<string, MockFileData>
    {
        { @"c:\myfile.txt", new MockFileData("Testing is meh.") },
        { @"c:\demo\jQuery.js", new MockFileData("some js") },
        { @"c:\demo\image.gif", new MockFileData(new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0xd2 }) }
    });
    var dataProcessor = new DataProcessor(fileSystem);

    // Test logic here...
}
```